# Java, Spring 3.0.5 integrating with Apache tiles 2.2.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

Following this tutorial:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/07/spring-3-mvc-tiles-plugin-tutorial-example-eclipse.html

Tiles configuration ( tiles.xml ) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="base.definition"
        template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/menu.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="contact" extends="base.definition">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Contact Manager" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/contact.jsp" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="hello.spring3.controller" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" 
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

when i run it, i get error:
http://pastebin.com/KY541YKD

what could be the problem? if you have any questions about other files/configuration, ask me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Rule
```

It looks like your missing a pre-3.0 version of [commons-digester](http://commons.apache.org/digester/).

Comment: Nope, I just downloaded the newest version from here http://commons.apache.org/digester/download_digester.cgi . the 3.0 version...and its sitting right there is my lib folder..

Comment: Version 3 of digester uses the `org.apache.commons.digester3` package name. Use the last 2.x version.

Comment: Hmm, that could be one thing, but im wondering if there is digester3 out, what must i do, to get it working with digester3...

Comment: You'll probably have to wait until Spring and/or Tiles updates. Either way, the point of changing the package name is so that you can have both digester2 and digester3 in the classpath without any issues.

Comment: Hmm okay, only problem is, I cant find any place to download the latest 2.x digester from..

Comment: A little effort goes a long way... http://www.reverse.net/pub/apache//commons/digester/binaries/

Comment: @JeremyHeiler I've been trying same tutorial, but I got `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory`. Thought that maybe issue was with `slf4j-log4j12-1.4.2.jar`, so I replaced it with `slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar`, but still there was no result. Same error. Plus at the top it gave `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 12`. On that line I have `<jsp:forward page="contacts.html"></jsp:forward>`. Like in tutorial. Could you help me also?

Comment: @Eugene: You're probably missing slf4j-api.jar

Comment: @JeremyHeiler yep. Fixed it for some time now, but still thanks.